# How to do ldapsearch with multiple filters?

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am doing an ldap search like below to get the info for a person,

```
ldapsearch -LLL -H ldaps://ldap.xyzcorp.com:636 -D 'xyzcorp\jack1' -W -x -b 'dc=xyzcorp,dc=com' sn=Ready
```

"sn" name "Ready" here is the last name of the person, but it returns multiple results who have the same last name "Ready", so I want to add multiple filters to search for both first name and last name like below:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -H ldaps://ldap.xyzcorp.com:636 -D 'xyzcorp\jack1' -W -x -b 'dc=xyzcorp,dc=com' sn=Ready AND givenName=Bill
```

but the result returned still contains multiple persons with the same last name "Ready". I am not sure which part is incorrect.

Can you please help me with this command?

Comment: Yo need to look up the syntax for LDAP filters. There is no AND keyword. Off topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't used ldapsearch.  That said, the custom LDAP query to return only the one person with sn=Ready and givenName=Bill if you can tack that onto your command would look like:

> ldapsearch -LLL -H ldaps://ldap.xyzcorp.com:636 -D 'xyzcorp\jack1' -W
>   -x -b 'dc=xyzcorp,dc=com' "(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(sn=Ready)(givenName=Bill))"

Comment: Thanks! I just tried. it works for me. I didn't the syntax is like "(&(filter)(filter)(filter))".